# Finding the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of this problem. I pretty much know you have to multiply by the conjugate but I get lost after I do that.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) - 1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to multiply by a conjugate. **Hint**: $1-x=(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{\frac 1 {\sqrt x}-1}{1-x}$$

This is

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\frac{{1 - \sqrt x }}{{1-x}}$$

Can you move on with that? (With anon's hint maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{1/\sqrt{x}-1}{1-x} & = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1 - (\sqrt{x})^2} = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{x}}{(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})}\\
& = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac1{(\sqrt{x}+1)} = \dfrac12
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
-\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{1 / \sqrt{x} - 1}{1-x} &=& \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{1 / \sqrt{x} - 1}{x-1}\\
&=& \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{1 / \sqrt{x} - 1}{x-1}\frac{1/\sqrt{x}+1}{1/\sqrt{x}+1}\\
&=& \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{1/x - 1}{(x-1)(1/\sqrt{x}+1)}\\
&=& \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1/\sqrt{x}+1}\times \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1/x - 1}{x-1}\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\times \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1/x - 1}{x-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$
This limit can be evaluated by noting that substituting $1/x$ for $x$ gives one over the limit, but should give the same value since $x\to 1$ is the same as $1/x\to 1$, thus the limit $L$ satisfies $L=1/L$, so $L=1$. This gives us a final answer of $-1/2$.

Comment: I apologize, and thank you for your answer but it was actually 1-x, not x-1!

Comment: @Jamie I modified the answer to adapt it, noting that $1-x=-(x-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

\begin{align}
&L = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1}{1-x}\\
&L = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{1}{-2x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \cdot -1\\
&L = \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{1}{2x^\frac{3}{2}}\\
&L = \dfrac{1}{2}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve it elementarily:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) - 1}{1-x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) - 1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) + 1}{(1 / \sqrt{x}) + 1}=\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{1-x}{2x(1-x)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) - 1}{1-x}$.

We substition $\sqrt {x}=t$, hance we:

If $ x\longrightarrow 1\Rightarrow t\longrightarrow 1. $

From here for the given limits have:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(1 / \sqrt{x}) - 1}{1-x}$=$\lim\limits_{t\to 1} \frac{\frac{1}{t} - 1}{1-t^2}$=$\lim\limits_{t\to 1} \frac{\frac{1-t}{t}}{1-t^2}$=$\lim\limits_{t\to 1} \frac{1-t}{t(1-t)(1+t)}$=$\lim\limits_{t\to 1} \frac{1}{t(t+1)}$=$\frac{1}{2}$